# Distinguish between environments with RNFirebase

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm using RNFirebase to integrate firebase analytics into react-native ios application, I'm not sure though what's the best way to distinguish between prod/dev environments.

I've found one possible solution on Swift

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyGoogleService", ofType: "plist")
guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

else { assert(false, "Couldn't load config file") } 
FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)
```

But I'm looking for a some sort of RNFirebase api to support this. Any thoughts? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by having multiple `google-services.plist` files outside your ios directory and use package scripts to overwrite the one in the ios directory as and when needed.

Someone touched on this [here](https://medium.com/@egunsoma/firebase-environments-with-react-native-dev-staging-prod-3832d7d22a80) and in [this issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/452). @akshetpandey's comment on the issue seems the most elegant way of doing it.

It's on our todo list to document this, we'll get to it as soon as we can.